# C dynamic memory problems with malloc() and free()

Tags: c, memory-management, memory-leaks, gdb, free

I dynamically allocated 2 different arrays with 1 million cells each. One array holds integers and one array holds pointers to strings of fixed length. When I run my program using gdb I'm getting the error: `free(): invalid next size (fast)`. I must be freeing memory in an illegal way, but I can't figure out how. I've posted a brief snippet of my code below where I am using malloc and free. Can you tell me what I'm doing incorrectly? Thank you.

Comment: *one array holds pointers to strings of fixed length* Then don't use `malloc()` for that. Also always check `malloc()`'s return value against `NULL` and don't write `x -> y` it's horrible, just `x->y` is good, because this kind of operator makes the expression a one thing unlike other operators, the same goes for `.`.

Comment: Are you sure you passed the right pointer to the freeing function, or that you didn't do it twice?

Comment: @iharob, Sorry, I should have mentioned that I may not be using 1 million cells in the future, it might vary depending on the input.

Comment: People are generally recommended to post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Your code is a prime example where having done this would have already told you that the code you've posted *works* indicating a problem elsewhere. http://ideone.com/xmunl3

Comment: @kfsone, looks useful, will do that in the future.

Comment: @TheEyesHaveIt If you're going to use fixed sized strings like that, consider using a typedef like this: http://ideone.com/2rwXb2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Except for being a bit strange, (see iharob's comment,) the code you are showing us appears correct.

The error is most probably not in the code you are showing us.

What is probably happening is that somewhere else you are filling-in those "words" of yours with characters, and you are storing more than 20 characters starting at the address of `wc->allWords[i]`.  So, you are writing past the end of a block of memory, and over the header of the next block of memory.

Then, later, the address of the block you are trying to free is correct, but you have damaged the header of the block, so `free()` fails.

Comment: Thanks, I'll look into that. Also, what do you mean by 'damaged the header'?

Comment: "damaged" in this case means "overwritten".  The C runtime had some values stored there, and you may have written characters over them.